# Как вырвать из столбика в консоли первую строку?

Tags: c#

есть столбик из цифр полученный из json ответа, из группы messages
вопрос, можно ли как-то только один id письма спарсить из ответа?
https://prnt.sc/qk9ii6
id я получаю из всех писем({})(на скриншоте их 2, но сейчас их около 10), можно ли только из первого получить id?

если нет, то как мне вырвать из уже вырванных id(из ответа json) только первый?
И набор чисел при каждом запуске программы разный(ведь это id писем, а письма приходят при каждом запуске программы), как мне вырезать из этого столбика первую строку? 
Прошу прощения за странный(возможно) вопрос, но я не смог найти ответ на него ответ

```
 код, откуда я получаю эти цифры 

string str3 = моя ссылка
        var json = JObject.Parse(str3);
    foreach (var ite2 in json["body"]["messages"])
                    {
             string hus = ($"{ite2["id"]}");
                        Console.WriteLine(hus);
```

что приходит в итоге

```
15782924340302058943
15780472500321295623
15778606990624433744
15777901380128771140
15648080331662639024
15648080260266414203
15648080170472550755
15648080090410296896
15643845560512851504
15643844801789366283
15643029081165707807
15643025930155177505
```

это id писем, полученных из ответа сервера, когда приходит новое письмо, получается вот это

```
15783686881870437498
15782924340302058943
15780472500321295623
15778606990624433744
15777901380128771140
15648080331662639024
15648080260266414203
15648080170472550755
15648080090410296896
15643845560512851504
15643844801789366283
15643029081165707807
15643025930155177505
```

здесь пришло новое письмо, id его 15783686881870437498, все остальные id смещаются вниз, мне нужно получить этот id нового письма

Comment: Этот столбик как в программу попадает?

Comment: Какой ответ ожидается? `27727272727` или `2`? Если вы запускаете программу -- то ловите столбик из неё же? (Тогда см. предыдущий вопрос от tym32167 - и строки в программе уже есть), если программа не ваша, то как вы ловите данные и можно ли считать, что вам достаточно показать как вырезать цифры до пробела и скастить к int?

Comment: ожидаю в ответе первую строку(27727272727), в этом столбике содержаться id писем, брал я их из json ответа от сервера, если пришло новое письмо и я запускаю программу, то к моим уже имеющимся id прибавляется ещё строка с набором цифр                    ' 33221123445
27727272727
62726261781
85994828282
27728282828
72781837377'

Comment: Вам дали решение задачи в тех терминах, в каких описали вы. Однако, у вас приходит json -- и более правильно просто распарсить его структуру и получить данные более удобным способом. Если вы хотите расти как программист -- окунитесь в тему парсинга jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если я все правильно понял то должно быть так :

```
           List<string> IdList = new List<string>(); 
            string str3 = моя ссылка
            var json = JObject.Parse(str3);
            foreach (var ite2 in json["body"]["messages"])
            {
                string hus = ($"{ite2["id"]}");
                IdList.Add(hus);
                Console.WriteLine(hus);
            }

            string lastid = IdList[0];
```

Comment: спасибо огромное